# Generate a sine wave with a predefined frequency and amplitude via DAC0 or DAC1 with Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-due, voltage, frequency, dac, sine-wave

Good Morning to everyone,
I am a PhD Student in experimental fluid mechanics at the University of Naples "Federico II", Italy. I am working on Arduino Due card and i am novel in applications using it. First, I need to generate a sine wave with variable frequency and amplitude. I tried to download several codes which are able to generate sine waves with a pre-defined frequency, but I would like to change this value of frequency at the beginning of the execution of the code. How could i do this ?
Second, I would like to change, in real-time, the output voltage of Arduino DAC0 or DAC1 at high speed to generate an arbitrary waveshape.. Is it possible?
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Dr. Alessandro Scala

Answer (score 1):

The formula commonly used to represent a sinusoidal signal is

V = A cos(ωt)

where A is the amplitude and ω is the angular frequency. This formula
should cope well with a variable amplitude. It is, however, not suitable
for a signal with variable frequency, because a discontinuity of the
frequency is not supposed to create a discontinuity in the signal.

The correct formula for a signal where both the amplitude and the
frequency can vary is

V = A(t) cos(φ(t))

where the phase is computed as

φ(t) = ∫ ω(t)dt

In terms of code, this means you need a static variable to keep track of
the current phase, and you have to update it periodically in order to
perform the numerical integration.

Here is a tentative implementation. I have qualified some variables as
`extern` only to hint that you are responsible for managing them. You
can remove the qualifier if you integrate this into your own code:

```cpp
// Defined and updated elsewhere.
extern const uint8_t output_channel;
extern float angular_frequency;  // in rad/us
extern float amplitude, offset;  // in ADC steps

// Call this as often as practical.
void update_output()
{
    // Compute the time delta.
    static uint32_t time_of_last_update;
    uint32_t now = micros();
    uint32_t dt = now - time_of_last_update;
    time_of_last_update = now;

    // Update the phase.
    static float phase;
    phase += angular_frequency * dt;
    while (phase >= 2 * M_PI) phase -= 2 * M_PI;  // unwrap

    // Output the signal.
    float output = offset + amplitude * cos(phase);
    analogWrite(output_channel, round(output));
}
```

Regarding the second part of the question (about arbitrary waveshapes),
it is, of course, feasible. You just have to pass arbitrary values to
`analogWrite()`.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Regarding the second part of the question, you are stating that i could be able to change the voltage in dependence of an input signal received by other pins ? Such as a measurement performed by a sensor read via Arduino and then change the voltage

Comment: @AlessandroScala: I am stating that you can change the output voltage however you like, and make it dependent on whatever you want.